# Optimize updating first, last, and second to last ranked value

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance, postgresql-13

I need to cache the first, last, and second to last time a thing happened per user. The history table I'm querying has hundreds of millions of rows (we're caching so we can truncate it), and the table I'm updating has dozens of millions.

Currently I'm doing it in batches of 1000 to avoid locking the tables. The query is like so:

```
with ranked as (
  select
      user_id,
      rank() over (partition by user_id order by created_at desc) as ranked_desc,
      rank() over (partition by user_id order by created_at asc) as ranked_asc,
      created_at
  from history
  where type = 'SomeType' and
        user_id between $1 and $2
)
update
  users u
set
  latest_at = (
    select created_at
    from ranked
    where ranked.ranked_desc = 1 and ranked.user_id = u.id
  ),
  previous_at = (
    select created_at
    from ranked
    where ranked.ranked_desc = 2 and ranked.user_id = u.id
  ),
  first_at = (
    select created_at
    from ranked
    where ranked.ranked_asc = 1 and ranked.user_id = u.id
  )
from ranked
where u.id = ranked.user_id
```

Relevant indexes on history are these. They are all btree indexes.

- (created_at)
- (user_id, created_at)
- (user_id, type)
- (type, created_at)

Can this be optimized? I feel this can be done without the subqueries.

Comment: Any particular reason to use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`? Will raise an exception for any duplicate in the used ranks. Also: please always declare your version of Postgres and provide a basic table definition with column types and constraints (`CREATE TABLE ...` statement).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Postgres 13, as tagged. I'm on mobile at the moment, but assume column types are sane (timestamps, properly declared foreign keys, etc). Thanks for the advice about rank, it shouldn't come up, but I'll switch it out.

Comment: It would help to know if `(user_id, created_at)` is `UNIQUE`. (Your use of `rank()` indicates as much!) Or can there be multiple entries with the same timestamp?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter It is not a unique index, but you can assume it is effectively unique.

Comment: Have you considered using a trigger to update the users table every time a new row is entered in the history table?

Comment: @BlueStar We effectively have that now, but we just added it. This is to backfill the users columns so we can truncate the enormous history table.

Comment: Please consider [instructions for \[posgresql-performance\] questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since we have the all-important index on `(user_id, created_at)`, I suggest:

```sql
UPDATE users u
SET    first_at    = h.first_at
     , latest_at   = h.latest_at
     , previous_at = h.previous_at
FROM  (
   SELECT u.id, f.first_at, l.last[1] AS latest_at, l.last[2] AS previous_at
   FROM   users u
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT ARRAY (
         SELECT h.created_at
         FROM   history h
         WHERE  h.user_id = u.id
         AND    h.type = 'SomeType'  -- ??
         ORDER  BY h.created_at DESC
         LIMIT  2
         ) AS last
      ) l
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT created_at AS first_at
      FROM   history h
      WHERE  h.user_id = u.id
      AND    h.type = 'SomeType'  -- ??
      ORDER  BY created_at
      LIMIT  1
      ) f
   WHERE  u.id BETWEEN $1 AND $2
   ) h
WHERE  u.id = h.id
AND   (u.first_at    IS DISTINCT FROM h.first_at
    OR u.latest_at   IS DISTINCT FROM h.latest_at
    OR u.previous_at IS DISTINCT FROM h.previous_at);
```

This works with non-unique timestamps per `user_id`, too.

And it's ***very*** efficient if there are many rows per user. It's designed to avoid a sequential scan on the big table and make heavy use of the index on `(user_id, created_at)` instead.
Related:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Assuming most or all users get updated this way, we don't need an index on `users`. (For the purpose of this `UPDATE`, no index would be best.)

If there is only a single row in table `history` for a user, then `previous_at` is set to `NULL`. (Your original query has the same effect.)

Only users are updated where qualifying history rows are found.

This added `WHERE` clause skips updates that would not change anything (at full cost):

```
AND   (u.first_at    IS DISTINCT FROM h.first_at
    OR u.latest_at   IS DISTINCT FROM h.latest_at
    OR u.previous_at IS DISTINCT FROM h.previous_at)
```

See:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

The only insecurity is with `WHERE type = 'SomeType'`. If that's selective, a partial index with the same predicate would be better. Then we could even get index-only scans ...

Since the new query should be ***much*** faster, you might update more (or all) users at once.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot tomorrow. What's the purpose of the distinct from clauses? Is there any risk of locking the tables if I do it all at once?

Comment: `distinct from clauses`? You mean the two lateral subqueries? The `history` table is only read and not locked at all. Updated rows of `users` are locked till the end of the transaction.

Comment: The `u.first_at IS DISTINCT FROM h.first_at` clauses. What is their purpose?

Comment: I clarified explanation above. More details in the linked answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860. Also, to be clear: Updated rows of `users` are write-locked till the end of the transaction. (Readers are not blocked.)

Comment: This is significantly faster, amazing! This backfill should be done before Monday morning now. Thank you, I appreciate your help. I'm gonna go rewrite the other slow backfill queries.